# Devextreme react datagrid Sorting Maximum call stack size exceeded in extend.js

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, devexpress

I have used : https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/ 
width React Wrapper for it https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-react

The main problem is when I try to use default sorting functionality it throws

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at extend (extend.js:23)
    at extend (extend.js:50)
    at extend (extend.js:50)
    at extend (extend.js:50)
```

On official site I saw recommendation to use fixed amount of columns, and it works, but my task require dynamic creation of columns, so it wouldn't work for me.

I've tried implement sorting by switching column's sort option (from this guide : https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Widgets/DataGrid/Sorting/#API), but on call method `columnOption` it throws same error.

I would be need any additional information to solve this issue, please tell me.

Comment: Looks like a recursive function has been called but never exits. I can't see where, though

Comment: this function locate in node_modules/devextreme/core/utils/extend.js : 23 , but I actually can't find out, what I config wrong in component, that lead to error